# Community makes content edits?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits, community-user

In this particular [answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1575179/2) Community account made an edit - I always thought Community is a bot- account. It flipped the colour description of the functions wrongly - what is happening?

Needless to say human reviewers just approved the edit without checking it.

Comment: See also: [Edits by Community ♦](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6683). The FAQ post [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251) also mentions that: "Anonymous users can suggest edits to any post more than 10 minutes old. These edits are attributed to the Community ♦ user upon approval. They cannot suggest edits to tag wikis."

Comment: Note that a post "closed as duplicate by Community" really means by the OP themselves; another instance where Community is not the bot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The edit [was suggested by an anonymous user](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1281896), i.e. a user not logged in (usually because they don't have an account). If such an edit suggestion is approved, the edit is "credited" to [Community♦](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).